# Popen hangs on communicate

Tags: python, popen

I am writing a program to communicate to two programs:

```
output = Popen(shlex.split(query_cmd), stdout=PIPE,stdin=None)
cmd_out = [output.stdout]
while cmd_out:
readable,writeready,exceptready = select.select(cmd_out,[],[],timeout)
for f in readable:
    line = f.readline()
    snap_result=Popen(shlex.split("snap %s" % (line) ),stdout=PIPE,close_fds=True).communicate()[0]
    print snap_result
```

Supposedly query_cmd will continuously generate lines of result. snap should that use this line as argument, return results and terminate. This works on python2.4. However, on python2.6.6, it seems that the snap will hangs on reading the result. 
 If I change the query_cmd to "tail -f file". It seems to work too.

I am running this inside a csh script where both stdout/stderr are redirected to  a log file.

EDIT: Actually, it is weird, in csh, I redirected both stdout&stderr to log file. If I only redirect stdout, it is running fine. If I redirect stderr, it hangs. I think somehow the stderr is messed up between parent process of python and child process.

Comment: What happens if you comment out the `snap_result =` and following line, but instead just print out line?

Comment: If I comment that out, it will work, it will just print out the line

Comment: And what happens if you remove the close_fds? What happens if you replace "snap" with e.g. "echo"?

Comment: close_fds seems to be necessary. It is supposed to prevent python subprocesses share file handle.

Comment: Did you *try* not using close_fds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems not be the problem of the script but because the subprocess is expecting stdin input. Redirect the stdin to null device solve this.